# Check if all multiple strings exist in one line

Tags: awk, sed, sh

I have a file that have this info

```
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_ISIL03_091_871
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_NETAPP_7890_2D5_1D8
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_SAN_A
IRE_DRO_Fabric_B drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_B_ISIL03_081_873
IRE_DRO_Fabric_B drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_B_NETAPP_7890_9D3_2D8
IRE_DRO_Fabric_B drogesx0112_SAN_B
```

and wanted to check if multiple string were found per line. Tried this command but it's not working. Not sure if it's possible for the current text type?

```
grep 'drogesx0112.*ISIL03_091_871\|ISIL03_091_871.*drogesx0112' file  << tried this but not working
grep 'drogesx0112' file | grep 'ISIL03_091_871'                       << tried this but not working
```

Looking for this output (I'm actually looking for string1(**drogesx0112**) and string2(**ISIL03_091_871**)

```
>grep 'drogesx0112.*ISIL03_091_871\|ISIL03_091_871.*drogesx0112' file # command

>IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_ISIL03_091_871       < output
```

so it's like i wanted to check if **drogesx0112** and **ISIL03_091_871** are present in a single line in a file.

Comment: Could you please do mention which all are those strings which you are looking to be present in a single line?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, edited my post. Not sure if i make any sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not looking for any order and simply want to check if both strings are present in a single line or not then try following.

```
awk '/drogesx0112/ && /ISIL03_091_871/' Input_file
```

---

---

***In case you are looking for sequence of strings in line:***

- If your line has `drogesx0112` first and then `ISIL03_091_871` then try following.

```
awk '/drogesx0112.*ISIL03_091_871/' Input_file
```

- If your line has `ISIL03_091_871` first and then `drogesx0112` then try following.

```
awk '/ISIL03_091_871.*drogesx0112/' Input_file
```

Comment: btw, i stored both drogesx0112 and  ISIL03_091_871 in a variable and it didn't work. tried replacing ' with " but still no output. Would you know how can i handle that?

Comment: @gafm, IMHO one post one question only please. Request you to open a new question with hew details in it, else users may get confuse in here, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: got it on another thread. Mind to take a look? :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64560253/print-variable-inside-forward-slash?noredirect=1#comment114156555_64560253

Comment: I believe @anubhava sir has added a nice dup to it, you could check it and if you have questions you could discuss in that post's comments cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Simple awk

```
$ awk ' /drogesx0112/ && /ISIL03_091_871/ ' gafm.txt
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_ISIL03_091_871
$
```

Simple Perl

```
$ perl -ne ' print if /drogesx0112/ and /ISIL03_091_871/ ' gafm.txt
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_ISIL03_091_871
$
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/drogesx0112/!d;/ISIL03_091_871/!d' file
```

Delete the current line if it does not contain `drogesx0112` and delete it if does not contain `ISIL03_091_871` too.

Another way:

```
sed -n '/drogesx0112/{/ISIL03_091_871/p}' file
```

A third:

```
sed '/drogesx0112/{/ISIL03_091_871/p};d' file
```