# Print variable inside forward slash

Tags: bash, awk

I wanted to pass on the variable inside the forward slash using the awk command.

```
host=drogesx0112
sto=ISIL03_091_871
```

Tried running this command but no ouput.

```
> awk "/${host}/ && /${sto}/" file
```

sample file:

```
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_ISIL03_091_871
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_NETAPP_7890_2D5_1D8
IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_SAN_A
IRE_DRO_Fabric_B drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_B_ISIL03_081_873
IRE_DRO_Fabric_B drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_B_NETAPP_7890_9D3_2D8
IRE_DRO_Fabric_B drogesx0112_SAN_B
```

Looking for this output.

```
]$ awk "/${host}/ && /${sto}/" file
]$ IRE_DRO_Fabric_A drogesx0112_IRE_DRO_A_ISIL03_091_871
```

Comment: Use: `awk -v host="$host" -v sto="$sto" '$0 ~ host && $0 ~ sto' file`

Comment: You define `sto` but expand `${tpar}`.

Comment: apologies. I already updated my post.

Comment: @anubhava, it's printing all lines with $host

Comment: @gafm Can you please copy-paste the code from your post into new files in a new directory and rerun it to make sure the problem is still there?

Comment: @thatotherguy, i already did, but still no luck

Comment: @gafm How about [this complete example](https://repl.it/repls/BubblyAdventurousBit#main.sh) that `repl.it` executes as expected